# Extract character-based columns and add delimiter using cut, awk, or sed

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I have a file that looks like this:

```
foo 23   45
bar      46
baz 25   57
```

It is not a delimited file. Instead, the character-based columns have specific meanings, which are documented like this:

- Columns 1-3 represent a thing.
- Column 4 is filler.
- Columns 5-6 represent a thing.
- Columns 7-9 are filler
- Columns 10-11 represent a thing.

Note that (a) there are no delimiters (the filler columns are of irregular length) and (b) some of the meaningful columns are filled with spaces.

There are thousands of columns.

I would like to extract certain columns from this file and convert them to a more standard delimited format. Since there are thousands of columns, and the documentation only refers to the character-based column indices, I would like to use those indices in my command, rather than semantic column indices. For example, if I wanted the first and last columns, I would want the output file to look like this:

```
foo,45
bar,46
baz,57
```

and I would like the command to refer to these as 1-3 and 10-11, in line with the documentation.

I tried

```
cut -c 1-3,10-11 file.txt
```

but this does not produce a delimiter between the two semantic columns.

I could also try:

```
awk '{print $1,$3}' fieldwidths="3 1 2 3 2" file.txt
```

but this requires knowing the semantic columns indices rather than the character column indices. Given that there are thousands of columns, and the documentation only refers to the character column indices, this would be very hard. To get a sense for how hard this would be, see the documentation (about 25% of the way down) ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Dataset_Documentation/DVS/periodlinked/LinkPE17Guide.pdf. This is just one of dozens of similar datasets I would need to read.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask]. What did you try?

Comment: Please add your efforts in your question and let us know. Will also un-delete my answer then.

Comment: Apologies for not describing earlier attempts, and thank you @RavinderSingh13 for the `awk` suggestion. I've added a note about how there are thousands of columns, and the documentation refers only to the character-based column indices.

Comment: @csaid, still not clear, could you please describe more clearly about your sample of input and expected output and let us know then.

Comment: @csaid, fieldswidth works on character length concept. You could mention character lengths in its value like I shown in my answer and it should be good. Let us know more clearly what issue you are facing in it.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13. I think it might help to see the documentation. ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Dataset_Documentation/DVS/periodlinked/LinkPE17Guide.pdf 

If you scroll down about 25% of the way, you will see where where it starts.

```
457-458 filler

459 some thing

460-474 filler

475 some thing
```
Everything documented is character-based. Since there are so many character-columns, it is hard to know the semantic column indices, which are what's required in the `print` part of your `awk` command.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer:
The `gcut` from GNU Coreutils (not `cut` pre-installed on my mac) has an `--output-delimiter` option:

```
gcut -c 1-3,10-11 --output-delimiter=',' file.txt
```

Comment: With `awk` could you please try `awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {print substr($0,1,3),substr($0,10,2)}'  Input_file` once?